# Нарушение инкапсуляции при возврате указателей

Tags: c++, ооп, указатели, ссылки, инкапсуляция

Предположим есть класс `A`:

```
class A {
private:
    int* v;
public:
    A() {
        v = new int;
        *v = 7;
    }

    int* get() {
        return v;
    }
};
```

И есть код в `main()`:

```
int main() {
    A* a = new A();

    std::cout << *(a->get()) << "\n";

    int* v1 = a->get();

    *v1 = 3;

    std::cout << *(a->get());

    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении будет выведено `7` затем `3`. Следовательно таким образом я изменил значение на которое указывало приватное поле `v` класса `A`, следовательно нарушил инкапсуляцию. В данном примере использование указателей является излишним, однако, если бы я захотел хранить какие-либо объекты в куче, я должен был бы использовать указатели.

Вопрос: каким образом организовать класс `A`, чтобы хранить значение в куче, возвращать его (не копию), при этом не имея возможности изменить данное значение, **не** посредством методов класса `A` (через методы `A` значение должно быть изменяемым (константы не подойдут))?

Comment: `const int* get()` вас не устроит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В геттерах имеет смысл возвращать ссылку на объект с `const` квалификатором и применять этот же квалификатор для самого метода. Таким образом вызывающий код получит доступ к хранимому объекту без возможности его изменить, причем этот метод может быть вызвать и у неизменяемого объекта-хранилища:

```
int const & get(void) const
{
    assert(v);
    return *v;
}
```

Comment: для данной функции  assert  плохое решение

Comment: @VTT а почему надо возвращать ссылку, а не указатель?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам вообще возвращать значение указателя? Это ваше дело - как и где хранить значение. Так что я бы делал

```
class A {
private:
    int* v;
public:
    A():v(new int(7)) {}

    int get() const {
        // Можно добавить обработку нулевого указателя
        return *v;
    }
};
```

Ну, а если ну позарез нужно вернуть указатель - то, значит, клиент *должен* работать именно с указателем напрямую, и тогда о какой инкапсуляции можно говорить?...
Если вы хотите, чтоб он не мог менять данные по этому указетелю - просто возвращайте `const int*`:

```
    const int* get() const {
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: @wcobalt Не хочется рассматривать *сферического коня в вакууме* - для каждого случая исходя из ТЗ в большей степени подходит то или иное решение. Да, возвращается копия - но как именно это влияет на вопрос о применимости метода?

Comment: Не хотите копию, возвращайте константную ссыльку

Comment: @Harry в вопросе я указал, что требуется возвращать **не** копию.

Comment: Верните то, что вам нужно - например, `const int& get() const { return *v; }`. Вы же писали о возврате **значения**. В моем ответе как раз и возвращалось **значение**. Если нет четкого ТЗ, результат - ХЗ. Вы попросили что-то вроде "вернуть значение дважды два, но не копию четверки" - ну кто вам после этого доктор?

Comment: @Harry да вы правы. Действительно, я попросил вернуть значение. На самом деле я хотел, вернуть "что-нибудь через что можно получить значение, нельзя изменить значение и это не должно быть копией значения - т.е. по сути - указатель или ссылку" P.S. Извините, я плохо сформулировал вопрос